# How to get a single value from a query result in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get single value from DB with single query. i mean that i already featched all values in one query from that i need to get only one column value.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            $query = mysqli_query( $connection,"select * from register where password='$log_in_password' AND username='$log_in_username'");
            var_dump($query);
            $table = mysqli_fetch_all($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            var_dump($table);
```

assume columns are 
' userid    useremail   username    password    Name '

from php
var_dump($query) gives this..

```
object(mysqli_result)[2]
  public 'current_field' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'type' => null
```

var_dump($table) gives this

```
 array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'userid' => string '7' (length=1)
      'useremail' => string 'demo@gmail.com' (length=16)
      'username' => string 'demousername' (length=7)
      'password' => string 'demopassword' (length=5)
      'Name' => string 'demoname' (length=6)
```

so help me out with fetching only one column value's record (example insSelect * to select userid)

Comment: plz clarify your question a little bit more

Comment: from`select *` i am getting one entire row as a result and i got this in a variable called `$query` since it is having all value how to get a single value (where `select userid` suppose to give). how to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable $table is an array, so if you want only the userid, you just have to use

```
$table[0]['userid']
```

If you want to query only the userid change you query like this :

```
$query = mysqli_query( $connection,"select userid from register where password='$log_in_password' AND username='$log_in_username'");
$table = mysqli_fetch_all($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

And the result of $table will be :

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'userid' => string '7' (length=1)
```

$table will also be an array, and to acces userid you have to use again

```
$table[0]['userid']
```

Comment: i am getting `Undefined index: userid in C:\wamp\...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from register where password='$log_in_password' AND username='$log_in_username'");
$table = null;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $table = $row;       
}
print_r($table);
```

Comment: so from this i am getting 
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 7
            [useremail] => prabhu@gmail.com
            [username] => vignesh
            [password] => apple
            [Name] => prabhu
        )

)` so how to get second array value.. i am new to php please help

Comment: print_r($table[0]) to get second array value

Comment: @RajagopalPG i have updated the code now you will get all the values

Comment: @vishalshah no it would not because it had break to run only once and also limit one in sql but now it would. Please vote up the answer and mark correct that would be appreciated

Comment: @FaizRasool For $table =  Array ( [0] => Array ( [userid] => 7 [useremail] => prabhu@gmail.com [username] => vignesh [password] => apple [Name] => prabhu ) ) this array I said use $table[0] to get second array

Comment: @vishalshah oh he mean second value a inner array value?

Comment: @RajagopalPG clarify what you want? like what result you want

Comment: @FaizRasool that is what i thought

Comment: @vishalshah i think he is looking to get the all of the matching result which for me does not give a sense but let see what he say

Comment: `$table[0]['userid']` this is what i want and answer is already given .. thank you for helping me out.