# php- get associative array values

Tags: php, arrays

pls, i would like to get the values of the `$aa` variable, i'm using the `mysqli_fetch_all` because all the values need to be used in another layer.
  Thanks

`$aa = mysqli_fetch_all($ttt,MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Output with `var_dump($aa)`:

`array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["followe"]=> string(8) "bammyww " } [1]=> array(1) { ["followe"]=> string(5) "demo " } }`

i have tried using $aa['followe'] , but i'm getting invalid index error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a single value from a query result in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844569/how-to-get-a-single-value-from-a-query-result-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through it. It's an array containing associative arrays.

```
foreach($aa as $item)
{
    $item['followe'] // do something with this.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$aa['followe']`, try:

```
$aa[0]['followe'];
```

as its a `multi-dimension array`. And the right approach to get all the array element is using `foreach()` like:

```
foreach($aa as $item)
{
    $item['followe']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$aa[0]['followe'];
```

`$aa[0]` is `array(1) { ["followe"]=> string(8) "bammyww " }`

`$aa[0]['followe']` is `string(8) "bammyww "`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `array_column` as

`array_column($aa,'followe')`;//retrieves values associated with the key followe

Comment: i got this array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "bammyww " [1]=> string(5) "demo " }  , how do i get the bammyww and demo

Comment: To get bammyww,  do print_r($array[0]); replace the array variable with yours